# Exception Value: 'Form' object has no attribute 'attribute'

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to override `clean()` method of the form to check, whether attribute IBAN is unique or not. Each `user` can have IBAN. For some reason, django says that form has no attribute IBAN which isn't true. As you can see it's a first attribute of the form.

Do you know what's problem?

```
class TranslatorRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    IBAN = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=True)
    languages = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Language.objects.all(), label='Languages: ',
                                               help_text="You can choose from UNKNOWN levels, to gain level, you will be tested")

    def __init__(self,user,*args, **kwargs):
        super(TranslatorRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TranslatorRegistrationForm, self).clean()
        if len(UserProfile.objects.filter(IBAN=self.IBAN).exclude(user=self.user))>0:
            raise ValidationError
        return cleaned_data
```

TRACEBACK:

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register-as-translator/

Django Version: 1.8.12
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'SolutionsForLanguagesApp',
 'crispy_forms',
 'super_inlines',
 'django_tables2',
 'language_tests',
 'smart_selects',
 'django_extensions',
 'constance',
 'constance.backends.database',
 'nested_inline')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\SolutionsForLanguagesApp\views.py" in register_as_translator
  110.         if register_as_translator_form.is_valid():
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  184.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  176.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  393.         self._clean_form()
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_form
  417.             cleaned_data = self.clean()
File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\SolutionsForLanguagesApp\forms.py" in clean
  116.         if len(UserProfile.objects.filter(IBAN=self.IBAN).exclude(user=self.user))>0:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /register-as-translator/
Exception Value: 'TranslatorRegistrationForm' object has no attribute 'IBAN'
```

Comment: Can you show me traceback?

Comment: Ok, I've added a traceback at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Once you've called `super(TranslatorRegistrationForm, self).clean()`, you should be able to access the value of the IBAN field in `cleaned_data['IBAN']`. The attribute `self.IBAN` is a field definition, rather than the field's value. Actually, I'll make this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are [validating the value of a single field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) `iban`, it would be better to define a `clean_iban` method instead of `clean`:

```
def clean_iban(self):
    iban = self.cleaned_data['IBAN']
    # Note using exists() is more efficient and pythonic than 'len() > 0'
    if UserProfile.objects.filter(IBAN=iban).exists():
        raise ValidationError('Invalid IBAN')
    return iban
```

The `clean` method is meant for [validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). If you override `clean`, you can't assume that a value will be in `cleaned_data`.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(TranslatorRegistrationForm, self).clean()
    if 'iban' in cleaned_data:
        iban = cleaned_data['iban']
        if len(UserProfile.objects.filter(IBAN=self.IBAN).exclude(user=self.user))>0:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid IBAN')
    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've called `super(TranslatorRegistrationForm, self).clean()`, you should be able to access the value of the IBAN field in `cleaned_data['IBAN']`. The attribute `self.IBAN` is a field definition, rather than the field's value.

Comment: You can't assume that 'IBAN' will be in `cleaned_data`. Your code should use something like `if 'IBAN' in cleaned_data` or `iban = cleaned_data.get('IBAN')`, to avoid a `KeyError`.

Comment: @Alasdair We have to assume that IBAN may not be in cleaned_data when overriding clean() method and don't have to assume that if we override (resp. creating) clean_IBAN() method? (According to your answer)

Comment: @Milano Yes, that's right. See the docs for [`clean_<field>`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) and [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) that I linked to for examples and an explanation.

Comment: Okay, I'll leave this answer unedited, since the comments don't make sense otherwise.